# Assets window brings up the front-end of the website

Tags: assets, pixelandtonic

I've got a site running on a client's server and when we go to add a file, the Assets modal brings up the front-end of the website.

Not sure if this is due to us making index.html the default directory file prior to us making the site live.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All sorted added the assets config overrides of

```
$config['assets_cp_path'] = "./system/";
$config['assets_site_url'] = "/index.php";
```

and we're good.

Comment: For other users in the future, this is very similar to http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/18119/ which has some other troubleshooting suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. My modal was empty, but adding

```
$config['assets_site_url'] = "/index.php";
```

Fixed it for me.

Assets 2.4
EE 2.7.3